# ControlToValidate doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I'm trying to add RequiredFieldValidator behind the `<input>`.

The following is my code:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="MID" />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" 
            runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <br />
    </div>
</form>
```

Then, I'm trying to assign the ControlToValidate to be MID, which is the id of the input text. However, there isn't anything available in the ControlToValidate:

[image]

Then, I just type MID in it and run the program,

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="MID" />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" 
            runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ControlToValidate="MID"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <br />
    </div>
</form>
```

and I get this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been about 5 or 6 years since I last wrote an ASP.Net website, but I'm sure you can only use server side validators on server side input controls. Your form doesn't contain any server side input controls.
Your `<input type="text" id="MID" />` should be an `asp:TextBox` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Add `runat="server"` to input element or use ASP.NET TextBox control (`asp:TextBox`)